# Permissions not applied to folder on Brazilian machine, how to fix that?

Tags: windows, vbscript, icacls

I am applying permissions to a folder using RunWait by icacls.

It is working correctly on windows 10 64bit English machine.

But when I ran on the Brazilian machine, it is not applying.

So ran the command manually on the Brazilian machine and got below error.

Operation failed Return code 1332.

And it described as "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

And I understood Users is written as Usuarios in the Brazilian machine.

But how to set permissions to Users folder using a language independent code so that it would apply to all the machines even the languages are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Installshield ISLockPermissions table instead of LockPermissions table, I am able to add the settings in an msi and installed that to apply the permissions.

We need to set this option.
[image: Custom Installshield Handling]

Answer (score 0):

You might think that the `Users : Usuarios` difference would cause issues but it actually shouldn't.  The Brazilian machine should still have a `Users` folder, and uses the contents of a `Desktop.ini` file to tell Windows Explorer to show the localized name `Usuarios`.

If you aren't already, use a [Special Folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) to start out the path you are feeding to `icacls`.  This technique can prevent many issues that arise due to variations in system configuration.  For example, to change the permissions on `C:\Users\testUser\Sample Folder\` you can use `%UserProfile%\Sample Folder\`.